# Delete Row Based on Partial Contents of Cell

Tags: vba, excel, replace

I am trying to create a VBA script that will go through column "A" in my spreadsheet and delete any Row that starts with a cell that contains the words "Div Code:"
The problem is, that the cells contain a lot more text after "Div Code" and I can't figure out how to make the .replace function work on partials.
Here's what I have thus far:

```
Sub FindDivCode()


  With Intersect(Columns("A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    .Replace "Div Code", "#N/A", xlPart
    .Replace "Date", "#N/A", xlPart
    .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
  End With
End Sub
```

This script works for the "Date" cells, but not the "Div Code" Cell's.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Paul

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the cells of the column A and, after having checked if the cell Ax starts by "Div Code", delete the entire row:

```
For j = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row To 1 Step -1
    If InStr(Range("A" & j).Value,"Div Code") = 1 Then
        Rows(j).Delete
    End If
Next j
```

Comment: If you are looping through and deleting rows you want to step backwards through the loop with `For j = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row To 1 Step -1` and cut out the `j = j - 1` line.

Comment: @D_Zab thank you, it makes actually more sense. I edited my answer.

Comment: You could simplify your conditional statement by using `InStr` instead

Comment: @Jeanno thanks to you as well, I've written the code too fast. It's actually simplified with InStr, I've made your suggested edit.

Comment: Il n'y a pas de quoi!

Comment: Thanks for your help guys! I can't get either answer to work, it's saying that the "If Instr" line "expected a list separator."

Comment: @PaulLeavitt try it now, I made another mistake (too tired today :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension to the solution given by Matteo. Credit should go to him

```
    Sub FindDivCode2()
        For j = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row To 1 Step -1
            If InStr(Range("A" & j).Value,"Div Code") = 1 Or  InStr(Range("A" & j).Value,"Date") = 1Then
                Rows(j).Delete
            End If
        Next j
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again Jeanno, This looks closer to working, but I'm still getting "Run-Time Error '13': Type Mismatch" on line three. Any idea what's causing this?